# Show and manipulate a vector in a circle

Tags: matrix

I first want to show the trigonometric circle with a vector written in matrix form and then I want to manipulate the schema.

I tried:

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, Circle[], Green, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}], Blue, 
  Flatten[{( {{Cos[Theta], -Sin[Theta]},{Sin[Theta], Cos[Theta]}} ).
  ( {{1},{0}} )}] }, Axes -> True, ImageSize-> 200]]
```

I think the probleme is on `Flatten[...]`.

Moreover I want to manipulate the `Theta`, but  the `Show[...]` doesn't work.

Comment: Notice that your `Flatten[...]` expression could be reduced to `{{Cos[Theta], -Sin[Theta]}, {Sin[Theta], Cos[Theta]}}.{1, 0}`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this roughly what you are looking for? In any case, perhaps this will give you a head start in the right direction:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Red, Circle[],
   Green, Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
   Blue, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {{Cos[Theta], -Sin[Theta]}, {Sin[Theta], Cos[Theta]}}.{1, 0}}]
  }, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 200
 ],
 {{Theta, Pi/3}, 0, 2 Pi}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]